# Error when trying to bind the value of a setter

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, binding, setter

I have the following XAML:

```
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                ...
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                ...
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        </Grid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                ...
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                ...
```

When the page loads, I'm getting the following `XamlParseException`:

> Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.Setter.Value'. [Line: 69 Position: 63]
>
> > InnerException:
> >     NotSupportedException: Cannot set read-only property ''.

The line number in the error corresponds to the `Grid.Row` setter; if I put a hard-coded value instead of a binding, it works fine (but obviously it's not what I want).

What's going on? The inner exception message makes no sense; I'm not setting any read-only property, and I'm certainly not setting a property with no name!

I'm new to Windows Phone, but I'm pretty sure the same code would work fine in WPF... Is binding in a setter not supported on WP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicions seem to be right - according to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/05/07/one-more-platform-difference-more-or-less-tamed-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better.aspx?Redirected=true), WP doesn't support Binding in the Value of a Setter.

There is also a workaround given in the article, [there has also been an update](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/02/as-the-platform-evolves-so-do-the-workarounds-better-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better-er.aspx?Redirected=true) and [another article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/10/the-taming-of-the-phone-new-settervaluebindinghelper-sample-demonstrates-its-usefulness-on-windows-phone-7-and-silverlight-4.aspx). To be honest - I haven't played with those examples, but maybe they will help you somehow.

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm (once I figured out how to use it...)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Then I'm glad I've managed to help. Good luck.