# Binding SelectedItems in ListView to a ViewModel in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following code:

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyListTemplate}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

With the following DataTemplate:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!-- Data Template for the ListView -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyListTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" />
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EntryDate}" TextAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Url}" TextAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" TextAlignment="Left" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

In my ViewModel I have the following:

```
private ObservableCollection<MyModel> myList;
public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyList {
    get { return myList; }
    set {
        myList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MyList");
    }
}

public IEnumerable<MyModel> SelectedItems {
    get { return MyList == null ? null : MyList.Where(e => e.IsSelected); }
}
```

And in my Model I have among others, my `IsSelected` property:

```
private bool isSelected;
public bool IsSelected {
    get { return isSelected; }
    set { Set(ref isSelected, value); }
}
```

I can see that the `SelectedItems` has all the elements that `MyList` has, however, when I select a few in the UI, the property `IsSelected` is not updated, they all remain false.
So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the `MyListTemplate`?

Comment: The question is updated with the DataTemplate.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on the setter of `IsSelected` to check if it is getting called when you click on an item?

Comment: It is only set when I am filling the collection the first time. When I select/unselected the set is not triggered, but I don't know why.

Comment: Strange, I just tested it in WPF and it is working. Cannot test on WP8.1 because I don't have it

Comment: Are you using a ListView or ListBox? Are you doing it with the same code?

Comment: ListView. I exactly copied your code (except the method `Set(ref isSelected, value)`)

Comment: Please show more of the MyModel class - what is the Set method doing?

Comment: The rest of the class is just a normal class, there's nothing extra to it.

Comment: In two hours I'll be able to do that. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [YossiStarz in MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0304cdb4-320c-420f-8bcb-3e2d2367b1d9/binding-selecteditems-in-listview-to-a-viewmodel-in-windows-phone-81?forum=wpdevelop#dd8c2c79-4190-4cfb-943a-b50093cfb72b), I managed to solve my problem. So here's his solution:

> The problem is that you cant use Style to SetBinding on the element
>   that you put the style on. This is because the style is created once
>   when the listview is created and not for each of the item containers.
>   what you actualy did, is creating a style object that have a setter
>   object that it's Value property is bounded to the IsSelected of the
>   DataContext of the Style parent (witch it doesn't have). This binding
>   occurs to set the value of the Value property in the setter. If it
>   would have succeed to get value, this was the value it would set to
>   all of the items containers.
>  I have a solution for you.
>  First
>   and the simplest, create this helper class:

```
public class Helper {
    public static string GetIsSelectedContainerBinding(DependencyObject obj) {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(IsSelectedContainerBindingProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsSelectedContainerBinding(DependencyObject obj, string value) {
        obj.SetValue(IsSelectedContainerBindingProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsSelectedContainerBinding.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedContainerBindingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsSelectedContainerBinding", typeof(string), typeof(helper), new PropertyMetadata(null, IsSelectedContainerBindingPropertyChangedCallback));

    public static void IsSelectedContainerBindingPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(d, ListViewItem.IsSelectedProperty, new Binding() {
            Source = d,
            Path = new PropertyPath("Content." + e.NewValue),
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
        });
    }
}
```

> Now change the setter to be like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="local:Helper.IsSelectedContainerBinding" Value="IsSelected"/>
</Style>
```

> This should apply SetBinding to each container that is created.

Comment: Just for future reference, a similar question was asked here - no bindings in Setters, yeah. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857505/how-do-i-do-bindings-in-itemcontainerstyle-in-winrt

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I suppose at the time (2012) the available version did not permit that.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had the same solution and was about to give up.  The key was prefixing "Content.".  Thanks again!!!!

Comment: Are Bindings in Setters supported in Universal Windows Applications?

Comment: @SuperJMN I don't think they are, at least not natively: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518133/error-when-trying-to-bind-the-value-of-a-setter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518133/error-when-trying-to-bind-the-value-of-a-setter)