# Style.Setter with Binding in Universal Windows Applications

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

As stated in the question below, **Setters cannot contain Bindings in Windows RT/Phone 8.1**

=> [Binding SelectedItems in ListView to a ViewModel in Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345820/binding-selecteditems-in-listview-to-a-viewmodel-in-windows-phone-8-1)

Has this changed in the new Universal Windows Applications?

Still not Bindings in values?

Comment: Apparently not. You could however easily try it yourself.

Comment: I haven't been successful, but maybe there another way to get the same effect. The proposed solution feels like a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to the DataContext using the normal ways, but **you can do it** using other (smart) methods:

See the below article - it provides a "helper" that allows to bind to the DataContext with a Setter.

http://dlaa.me/blog/post/10089023